# The operator $\frac{D}{e^D-1}$ in definition of Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: bernoulli-polynomials

I am trying to understand [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials), and so I came across this abomination in the article:
$$
B_n(x) = \frac{D}{e^D-1} x^n
$$
where $D$ is the differentiation operator and the fraction is "expanded out as a formal power series"

Since we have $$\frac{t}{e^t-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{t^n}{n!}$$ Does this imply that I should interpret the fraction as
$$
\frac{D}{e^D-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{D^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: Yes, see (holomorphic) functional calculus

Comment: Yes. This sort of "abomination" is common for many purposes.

Comment: First time I saw the fraction of doom was a few months ago, and now today I finally understand it. Thanks all

Comment: This abomination is also used to "derive" the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. See for example Spivak - Calculus 3rd edition, problems in the chapter on complex power series.

Comment: I just learned about Euler-Maclaurin the other day, and I was wondering how that was proved. Now I will look into that. It's all coming full circle

Answer (score 3):

I'm so silly
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{D}{e^D-1}x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k \frac{D^k(x^n)}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n B_k \frac{(n)_k}{k!} x^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k x^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_{n-k} x^k \\
&= B_n(x)
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We are looking for solutions to

$$B_n(x+1) - B_n(x) = n x^{n-1}$$

that is

$$(e^D -1) B_n(x) = D x^n$$

So take

$$B_n(x) = \frac{D}{e^D-1} x^n$$

Note: $D$ is the derivative. $B(x+1) = e^D B\,(x)$ from Taylor's formula.

$\bf{Added:}$

The [Euler polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerPolynomial.html), satisfying

$$\frac{1}{2}( E_n(x+1) + E_n(x))= x^n$$

are given by

$$E_n(x) = \frac{2}{e^D+1} x^n$$

They are also useful in calculating alternating sums

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k (x+k)^n$$

Comment: That is a neat proof. How do you justify the division of $e^D-1$?

Comment: The division $\frac{D}{e^D-1}$ is formal, but works when RHS is a polynomial. There is something similar with Euler polynomials. Learned this from a basic book, probably Norlund has it.